# Are myths related to and comparable to Draupadi found in other culture's myths also?

Tags: comparative, hindu

The myth of Draupadi is found in the famous Hinduism mythological epic poem Mahabharat where she is disrobed by her brother in law in front of her five powerful husbands, in the King's Court full of great righteous super powerful warriors, all bearing silent spectators to the act being committed.

For a starter pack, kindly go through the character's Wikipedia page -

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draupadi

Ultimately as per different versions either she is divinely rescued via supernatural intervention from the Hindu deity Krishna, whom she desperately prays as the last resort, or in some other versions of the epic it is found that she herself gets out of the glaring crime through her adept speech on rules, regulations, and arguments on Justice and righteousness.

My question revolves around comparative myths of similar nature that maybe found in other cultures. Need not be complete copy paste, but atleast some elements of the above written facts and themes must be present in the parallel myth.

Please give any similar instances, if any.

Comment: You may find the south Indian [Mahadevi akka](https://lingayatreligion.com/Sharanaru/Akkamahadevi) of interest.

Answer (score 0):

[Nahum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahum) 3:5

“Behold, I am against you,” declares the Lord of hosts;
“And I will lift up your skirts over your face,
And show to the nations your nakedness
And to the kingdoms your disgrace.

Answer (score 0):

Legends of Saint Agnes sometimes state that she was sentenced to be exposed naked to the public, and her hair grew so long as to cover her body, or a shining white garment appeared to cover her.

Saint Eulalia's naked body, after her martyrdom, was said to be covered up by a miraculous snowfall.